# Disable all listeners connected to queue

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Is it technically possible to enable and disable all the listeners listening to a particular queue?
For example i have all the connections details for queue and i dont have any listener details.I just want to disable them and enable them back

Comment: On the queue manager side you can use `DIS CONN` to find which connections are attached to a queue and you can use `STOP CONN` to kill those.  As to if the remote app which had the queue open then attempts to reopen the queue would depend on that applications error handling.   If this is what you are looking for I'll post a answer with the commands you can use.

Comment: Do you know how to do this using Java libraries ?

Comment: Would you not just bounce the JMS async listener that is running if you have access to the java side?

Comment: Or are you asking how to have a java program connect to the queue manager and perform the `DIS CONN`/`STOP CONN` actions?

Answer (score 0):

You can admin a QMANAGER and his object with "**Programmable Command Formats  (PCFs)**" if PCFs is active in yor Qmanager. PCFs are command for administration throw message send to QMANAGER. For example, tuning queue parameters such as maximum queue depth, maximum message length, and enabling and disabling queues.

In yor case you can ENABLE/DISABLE de GET propertie of yor QUEUE, for enable o disbale de get on that particular queue.

> https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086870_.htm